# Bootstrap 3 Modal with Ember.js, no data in modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use Bootstrap 3's modal along with Ember.js. So far, I have been unsucessfull. The data modal itself is not appearing, although the screen is doing the fade.
my app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        showGroups: function() {
            this.container.lookup('view:groups').append();
        }
    }
});

App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return groups;
    }
});

App.GroupsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "groups",
    classNames: ["modal", "fade"],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().modal('show');
        this.$().one("hidden", this._viewDidHide);
    },
    // modal dismissed by example clicked in X, make sure the modal view is destroyed
    _viewDidHide: function() {
        if (!this.isDestroyed) {
            this.destroy();
        }
    },
    // here we click in close button so _viewDidHide is called
    close: function() {        
        this.$(".close").click();
    }
});

var groups = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Family Reunion',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'California Trip',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Dream Vacations',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Fun for Kids',
    },
];
```

My templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <button class="btn actionBtn userControls" {{action showGroups}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> &nbsp My Favorites</button>
          <!-- Split button -->
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn secondaryBtn userControls"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  &nbsp Hello, <b>User</b></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn secondaryBtn dropdown-toggle userControls" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu secondaryMenu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="groups">>
      <div class="modal fade" id="favoritesModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title tertiaryHeading">My Favorite Groups</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {{#each model}}
                {{render "group" this}}
              {{/each}}
            </div>    

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn actionBtn">Create New Group</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
      </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="group">
      <button class="btn secondaryBtn groupBtn">{{name}}</button>
</script>
```

How can I make this work? I'm new to Ember, and not sure if I understand how to inject data into a view?

Comment: Could you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: If the answer below is not correct, I will.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues that are slowing you down.

First, your `'groups'` template is never being inserted into the DOM.  `this.container.lookup('view:groups').append()` does not do what you seem to think it does.  The Ember Way (tm) is to use an `outlet` for rendering nested templates, and modals are really just a special case of nesting.  (You can use the View Tree of the Ember inspector to see that the `'groups'` template is never inserted.)

I would recommend altering your `ApplicationRoute` to be this (use `actions` instead of `events`, and just `transitionTo` the `'groups'` route):

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        showGroups: function() {
          this.transitionTo('groups');
        }
    }
});
```

At this point you should see that the `'groups'` template is making it into the DOM, but it's still not being shown.  This is due to the second issue, which is that you have a modal inside a modal (yo dawg!).  Your `GroupsView` is creating a new element and setting class names of `modal` and `fade` on the new element.  Your `groups` template is being rendered into that element, but the outer div in your `groups` template has the class names of `modal` and `fade`.  The outer modal (created by `GroupsView`) is being "displayed", but since it contains content that is explicitly hidden (due to the `modal fade` classes) nothing is shown on screen.  You could either remove the outer div in your template, or remove the class names from `GroupsView`, and then display the modal with `this.$('#favoritesModal').modal('show')`.

Here's a working JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1311/edit